# Get containing path of lua file

Tags: filesystems, lua

I am wondering if there is a way of getting the path to the currently executing lua script file?

This is specifically not the current working directory, which could be entirely different. I know [luafilesystem](http://keplerproject.github.com/luafilesystem/index.html) will let me get the current working directory, but it doesn't seem to be able to tell the current executing script file.

Thanks

EDIT:
I'm not running from the standard command line interpreter, I am executing the scripts from a C++ binary via [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the Lua script is being run by the standard command line interpreter, then try `arg[0]`.

Comment: If I did dofile(subfile) within the original, would this method work for getting the path of the subfile?

Comment: @radman: no. Moreover, `dofile` uses whatever path it gets and so relative paths are relative to the current working directory of the process. If you want to track files given to `dofile`, you can redefine it.

Comment: and user could also use loadfile and then run the loaded file as a function call, you may have to redefine loadfile as well

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Lua 5.3. The `...` of the main chunk only returns the equivalent of `arg[1]` onwards.

Comment: @HishamHM, who said anything about `...`? `arg[0]` does work with Lua 5.3.

Comment: @lhf, sorry, I got things mixed up with `arg` in varargs going away after being deprecated in Lua 5.1. Indeed, relying on `arg` works when launching a script directly from an interpreter, but not when loading the same script with `loadfile`.

Answer (score 37):

This is a more elegant way:

```
function script_path()
   local str = debug.getinfo(2, "S").source:sub(2)
   return str:match("(.*/)")
end

print(script_path())
```

Comment: If the script is run without a path, such as `lua myscript` (in which lua assumes this means `./myscript`), this function returns `nil`. I suggest using `return str:match("(.*/)") or "."`

Comment: To make this work on Windows replace `str:match("(.*/)")` with `str:match("(.*[/\\])")`

Comment: Adding to HishamHM's comment: You should return `or "./"` so the function always returns a path ending with `/`.

Answer (score 8):

Shortest form which I have found looks like this:

```
debug.getinfo(1).source:match("@?(.*/)")
```

Index 1, 2- other - depends on which function in call stack you want to query. 1 is last called function (where you're in). If you're running in global context, then probably 2 is more appropriate (haven't tested by myself)

Comment: `arg[0]:match("@?(.*/)")` is work for me in run from console.

Answer (score 6):

As lhf says:

```
~ e$ echo "print(arg[0])" > test.lua
~ e$ lua test.lua
test.lua
~ e$ cd /
/ e$ lua ~/test.lua
/Users/e/test.lua
/ e$
```

Here's the same info using the debug.getinfo mechanism

```
~ e$ echo "function foo () print(debug.getinfo(1).source) end; foo()" > test.lua
~ e$ lua test.lua
@test.lua
~ e$ cd /
/ e$ lua ~/test.lua
@/Users/e/test.lua
/ e$
```

This is available from the C API [lua_getinfo](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_getinfo)

Answer (score 4):

The only reliable way to get what you want is to replace `dofile` with your own version of this function. Even the `debug.getinfo` method won't work, because it will only return the string passed to `dofile`. If that was a relative path, it has no idea how it was converted to an absolute path.

The overriding code would look something like this:

```
local function CreateDoFile()
    local orgDoFile = dofile;

    return function(filename)
        if(filename) then --can be called with nil.
            local pathToFile = extractFilePath(filename);
            if(isRelativePath(pathToFile)) then
                pathToFile = currentDir() .. "/" .. pathToFile;
            end

            --Store the path in a global, overwriting the previous value.
            path = pathToFile; 
        end
        return orgDoFile(filename); --proper tail call.
    end
end

dofile = CreateDoFile(); //Override the old.
```

The functions `extractFilePath`, `isRelativePath`, and `currentDir` are not Lua functions; you will have to write them yourself. The `extractFilePath` function pulls a path string out of a filename. `isRelativePath` takes a path and returns whether the given path is a relative pathname. `currentDir` simply returns the current directory. Also, you will need to use "\" instead of "/" on Windows machines.

This function stores the path in a global called `path`. You can change that to whatever you like.

Comment: fyi, you can perfectly use `/` for windows paths too.

Comment: also loadfile should be overridded

Answer (score 4):

I have written a function `getScriptDir` which uses the debug information like a few other people have suggested, but this one is going to work everytime (at least in Windows). But the thing is there are quite a few lines of code as it uses another function `string.cut` which i have created, which separates a string every given pattern, and puts it into a table.

```
function string.cut(s,pattern)
  if pattern == nil then pattern = " " end
  local cutstring = {}
  local i1 = 0
  repeat
    i2 = nil
    local i2 = string.find(s,pattern,i1+1)
    if i2 == nil then i2 = string.len(s)+1 end
    table.insert(cutstring,string.sub(s,i1+1,i2-1))
    i1 = i2
  until i2 == string.len(s)+1
  return cutstring
end

function getScriptDir(source)
  if source == nil then
    source = debug.getinfo(1).source
  end
  local pwd1 = (io.popen("echo %cd%"):read("*l")):gsub("\\","/")
  local pwd2 = source:sub(2):gsub("\\","/")
  local pwd = ""
  if pwd2:sub(2,3) == ":/" then
    pwd = pwd2:sub(1,pwd2:find("[^/]*%.lua")-1)
  else
    local path1 = string.cut(pwd1:sub(4),"/")
    local path2 = string.cut(pwd2,"/")
    for i = 1,#path2-1 do
      if path2[i] == ".." then
        table.remove(path1)
      else
        table.insert(path1,path2[i])
      end
    end
    pwd = pwd1:sub(1,3)
    for i = 1,#path1 do
      pwd = pwd..path1[i].."/"
    end
  end
  return pwd
end
```

**Note:** if you want to use this function in another OS than Windows, you have to change the `io.popen("echo %cd%")` in the **line 15** to whatever command gives you present working directory in your OS, e.g. `io.popen("pwd")` for Linux, and the `pwd2:sub(2,3) == ":/"` in the **line 18** to whatever represents the root directory in your OS, e.g. `pwd2:sub(1,1) == "/"` for Linux.

**Note2:** if you don't provide the `source` variable to the function via `debug.getinfo(1).source` when calling it, then it will return the path to the directory of the *file containing this function*. Therefore, if you want to get the directory of a file which you called via `dofile` or `loadfile`, you will have to give it the source, like this: `getScriptDir(debug.getinfo(1).source)`.

Answer (score 3):

This version of [anthonygore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23535333/79125) is cross-platform (handles Windows backslash paths) and works when the script is run without a path (returns relative path).

```lua
local function script_path()
    local str = debug.getinfo(2, "S").source:sub(2)
    return str:match("(.*[/\\])") or "./"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Lua debug library, which is part of the standard Lua distribution. You can use debug.getinfo to find the current file, or the file up N frames on the call stack:

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.9

Note that this is probably fairly slow, so it is not something you want to do on the fast path if you are worried about such things.

Comment: thanks for the idea but I think that is far too much of a filthy hack for my liking ;)

Answer (score 2):

if you want the actual path :

```
path.dirname(path.abspath(debug.getinfo(1).short_src))
```

else use this for full file path :

```
path.abspath(debug.getinfo(1).short_src)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the real path including the filename, just use the following

```
pathWithFilename=io.popen("cd"):read'*all'
print(pathWithFilename)
```

Tested on Windows.

**Explanation:**

`io.popen` - Sends commands to the command line, and returns the output.

`"cd"` - when you input this in `cmd` you get the current path as output.

`:read'*all'` - as io.popen returns a file-like object you can read it with the same kind of commands. This reads the whole output.

---

If someone requires the UNC path:

```
function GetUNCPath(path,filename)
local DriveLetter=io.popen("cd "..path.." && echo %CD:~0,2%"):read'*l'
local NetPath=io.popen("net use "..DriveLetter):read'*all'
local NetRoot=NetPath:match("[^\n]*[\n]%a*%s*([%a*%p*]*)")
local PathTMP=io.popen("cd "..path.." && cd"):read'*l'
PathTMP=PathTMP:sub(3,-1)
UNCPath=NetRoot..PathTMP.."\\"..filename
return UNCPath
end
```

Comment: This returns the working directory of the script, but that may not match the script directory (`lua path/to/script/s.lua`).

Answer (score 0):

```
arg[0]:match('.*\\')
```

If it returns nil try changing the `.\*\\\` with `.*/` and `arg[0]` with `debug.getinfo(1).short_src`.

But I find this to be the best and shortest way to get the current directory.

You can of course append the file you are looking for with the `..` operator. It will look something like this:

```
arg[0]:match('.*\\')..'file.lua'
```