# Lua, io.input() can't find file

Tags: input, io, lua

I have `myfile.txt` sitting in the same directory as my lua file, yet when I call `io.input("myfile.txt")` I get the error `bad argument #1 to 'input' (myfile.txt: No such file or directory)`.

I don't see how this can be going wrong, have I misunderstood Lua's I/O?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the path (eg. `"/home/username/myfile.txt"` on *NIX, `"C:\directory\myfile.txt"` on Windows). When you don't, the Lua interpreter expects the file to be in the same directory as the interpreter.

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380820/get-containing-path-of-lua-file) for an easy fix using `arg[0]` to get the current directory of the script being executed.

Comment: Thank you! However, I'm executing this code use Love2d, which might put a bit of a spanner in the works regarding getting the current directory. Any suggestions?

Comment: If Love2d doesn't give you a way to load resources itself then I would hope it gives you a way to get your base directory location.

Comment: If you're using Love2d, I strongly suggest you use the API function, `love.filesystem.read` (https://www.love2d.org/wiki/love.filesystem.read)