# What does the @ at sign mean in Lua?

Tags: lua, special-characters

I looked at [Get containing path of lua file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380820/get-containing-path-of-lua-file), and I can see that:

```lua
print(debug.getinfo(1).source)
```

... results with e.g.:

```
@/Users/e/test.lua
```

Apparently, as a path, this is a string - but what is the "at sign"/"at character" `@` there for; what does it mean?

It was otherwise quite difficult finding anything useful related to this, by doing an internet search for `Lua "at sign"` (even with quotation marks)

Comment: next time don't search the internet. search the Lua manual ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the function was defined in a file.

From the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: 4.7 The Debug Interface](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#4.7)

> The fields of lua_Debug have the following meaning:
>
> **source: the source of the chunk that created the function. If source
> starts with a '@', it means that the function was defined in a file
> where the file name follows the '@'**. If source starts with a '=', the
> remainder of its contents describes the source in a user-dependent
> manner. Otherwise, the function was defined in a string where source
> is that string.

The Lua manual lists other uses of @. For example `warn("@off")` can be used to turn off the emission of warnings.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer @Piglet - feels good to know where to finally find this information!