# How can I open a textfile, relative to an executed Lua file?

Tags: lua, scripting, filepath

I'm in the Lua console of the Bizhawk emulator. I want to edit Ram of a GBA game.

I have a directory with a Lua file and another folder, that has a text file in it. I managed to read text from it by using the absolute path but I want to make it work with the relative path.

I tried to use `arg[0]` to get the path of the file but it's nil.
And this outputs me 'ain': `debug.getinfo(1,"S").source:sub(2)`

Comment: which environment are you in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get containing path of lua file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380820/get-containing-path-of-lua-file)

Comment: I'm in the Lua console of the Bizhawk emulator. I want to edit Ram of a GBA game... Before I tested it in Zerobrane, there arg[0] and debug.getinfo(1,"S").source:sub(2)  works but in Bizhawks Lua Console it throws me errors. And no, your linked post doesn't answer my question because they do exactly what I already tried to do.

Comment: That's a Windows-based program, right?  What happens when you `print( io.popen('cd'):read('*a') )`

Comment: well if you cannot get the path using Lua's standard functions and there is nothing in the Bizhawk documentation you probably cannot get the file path. I suggest you get in touch with the developers then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this worked for me:
`print( io.popen('cd'):read('*a') )`

Thank you for your help!